# Firebase Authentication Failed - Expired Auth Token Discrepancy

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentication in my app (Google, Facebook and email). Everything works fine, but sometimes I get,

```
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Authentication failed: expired_token (Auth token is expired)
```

But if I check this,

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null
```

it returns **false** every time, so the **current user is not null** (according to Firebase)

I also have implemented this,

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuth -> {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                Intent intent = AuthFlowActivity.getCallingIntent(AuthFlowActivity.FORCE_LOGOUT);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                activityExitAnimation(BaseAppActivity.this);
            }
        });
```

The listener gets fired, but here also the **current user is never null**.

If I try to push any data to the Realtime Database at this stage, nothing gets pushed. I have also tried uploading files at this stage, it fails with permission denied exception.

**Why this discrepancy?**

If the token has expired, why the current user is never null? It should be. If not, how to identify correctly **if the user is signed in and his/her auth token is not expired**?

Comment: Are you seeing the token expiration once per hour?  I think that is the default lifetime and the token is automatically refreshed.  In your case, is the token not refreshing?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am seeing the token refresh every hour. In my case the token is not refreshed. Though this was not the case for months, all of a sudden this started to show up and I haven't changed one line of code which could affect this.

Comment: @qbix Any update on this?

Comment: I don't have any suggestions.  Has your apps SHA-1 fingerprint changed?